# Optimizing (DFT/MP2) small molecule dimers

Tags: density-functional-theory, gaussian, optimization

I'm attempting to optimize n-alkane dimers using MP2/DFT in Gaussian09. However the first one or two frequencies are always negative. Can these modes be ignored or do I need to do a tighter optimization?

Comment: What are the magnitudes of the imaginary frequencies? And, do you want to calculate the Gibbs free energy, or are you interested in other quantities instead? The answer will heavily depend on these two factors. See https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3942/is-it-right-to-neglect-very-small-imaginary-frequencies/8678#8678

Comment: The magnitude is about -28 wavenumber... I am looking for optimized geometries for further studies. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the threshold of the optimization process?

Comment: Try to check the initial geometry of your structure (Using Avogadro for example)

Comment: How are you accounting for BSSE?

Comment: @Wesley How does BSSE matter for this question?

Comment: You don't mention the size of the alkane. Nevertheless, as @wzkchem5 indicated, for really accurate thermochemistry, you'll want to work on eliminating those imaginary frequencies. IMHO, that's small enough you can ignore for many purposes. (For DFT, it can be due to grid issues, for example.)

Comment: @TristanMaxson good call, for geometry optimization it would not affect forces

Comment: the forces are converged for both optimization and freq calculations; however, it's interesting to learn how you alter the threshold values in opt freq calc? Let me know.

Comment: Yes, BSSE is a factor for small molecules. Hence BSSE is corrected by including counterpoise=2, and opt freq is performed on the last link.

Comment: The issues were solved now by taking care of many factors, i. symmetry of the molecules (geometry), ii. DFT-D3 dispersion iii. ultrafine grid iv. read the DFT-D3 Hessians to perform MP2 optimization/Freq. Finally, the negative frequencies have disappeared. Thanks for your comments, however, let the good thoughts keep come.

Comment: @TristanMaxson BSSE can effect geometry optimization which can effect frequencies. Don't trust me though, trust Stefan Grimme https://www.researchgate.net/publication/360100943_Best_Practice_DFT_Protocols_for_Basic_Molecular_Computational_Chemistry

Comment: @SubrataTewary Since you solved this problem, can you write a self-answer? It would be helpful for this community, and for future users! I've placed this question on [this list](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/323/5).

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing the OP's comment that describes how they managed to remove negative (imaginary) frequencies for their system:

1. Ensure correct symmetry of the molecular geometry
2. Include D3 dispersion for the DFT calculation
3. Use an ultrafine integration grid for the SCF
4. Use the DFT-D3 Hessians as a guess to perform the MP2 optimization/Freq.